# How to create a 'pure' virtualenv?

Tags: python, macos, dependencies, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtualenv and carefully track all dependencies. I created the env this way:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages purenv

cd purenv
source bin/activate
```

Then run this python script:

```
url = "http://localhost:6543/foo/",

hdrz = {
    "Accept" : "text/html",
    "account-code":"foo1234",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdrz)
```

I get this error:

```
  File "foo.py", line 10, in <module>
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdrz)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 229, in __init__
    self.__original = unwrap(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1075, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'

which python
/Users/foo.bar/workspace/purenv/bin/python
```

So, I'm using the python installed to the virtualenv, but the error is coming from outside the virtualenv (`/System/Library/Frameworks/...` and not `purenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages...` or the like).

How can I create a virtualenv where no external files are called?

Comment: That's part of the standard library, not an external package. This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: But if the python you're using is installed inside the virtualenv, why not install the standard libraries there too?

Comment: It isn't *"installed inside the virtualenv"*, it's all symlinks.

Comment: Well, I thought that was the point of virtualenv - was to create an environment that doesn't pollute or corrupt your system as a whole, but to keep it all constrained to a private area

Comment: Virtualenvs are for managing dependencies on third party packages, not the standard lib. You already have the standard lib, how exactly does that *"pollute or corrupt"* anything?

Comment: take it easy, it's just a question

Comment: I'm sorry if you consider that un-easy, I'm just trying to understand your requirement.

Comment: *"How can I create a virtualenv where no external files are called?"* - you can't, that's not the problem they're designed to solve. If you want a completely isolated environment, consider something like a Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
url = "http://localhost:6543/foo/",
```

To:

```
url = "http://localhost:6543/foo/"
```

You are sending a tuple, not a str.
Sorry for the bad english.